# NetSuite Suitescript 2.0 How can I access custom item options records?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve in a roundabout way since the straightforward way didn't work.

**The task:** Retrieve the customizable item options off of a purchase order item (using SuiteScript 2.0).

**The partial solution:** Currently, I extract the itemId off the PO using

```
po.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item' });
```

Then I load the item and extract the item options IDs and labels using

```
var optionIds = item.getValue({ fieldId: 'itemoptions' });
var optionLabels = item.getText({ fieldId: 'itemoptions' });
```

For item options that aren't List/Record type, (like freeform text personalization), I can then loop through the item options and extract their text off of the PO item using the following code.

```
for (var j = 0; j < optionIds.length; j++) {
    var option = po.getCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: optionIds[j].toLowerCase()
    });
    if (option !== null) {
        log.debug({title: 'option found', details: optionLabels[j] + ': ' + option});
    }
}
```

**The issue:** When the item option is a List/Record type, both `getCurrentSublistText` and `getCurrentSublistValue`return the internal ID of the list selection. For instance, if I have a custom item option for Shirt Color, and it uses the custom list Color, with Red being internal ID 2, then if my PO has an item with red shirt color on it, the option label will be "Shirt Color", but instead of "Red," the `option` will be 2, the internal ID from the Color list. I have no idea why `getCurrentSublistText` doesn't work for this use case, but I've accepted it, and I'm looking for a workaround.

My thought was, since the item option is a record in the UI (my field explorer extension says it has `recordType:"itemoptioncustomfield"`), I could just load it up using the option ID that I have, and if it has `fieldtype:"SELECT"`, I would get the internal ID of the List/Record selection (fieldId: `selectrecordtype`) then use `search.lookupFields` to get the actual value of my item option, instead of the internal ID. The only issue is, I can find no way to load (or search on) an item option. The record type does not seem to exist in SuiteScript (I believe in Suite Talk it does though). Is this a possible task? Even if my workaround can't work, is there another better workaround that I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance, I'm at a loss here.

Edit: Just to add further attempts, I found the `Field.getSelectOptions()` function today which looked really promising, since it would list all the select options of the item option and their values I would think. I tested it out on some other more basic fields on the order and it worked, however when I tried using `getCurrentSublistField` on the item option field (just as I used `getCurrentSublistValue` and `getCurrentSublistText`, the field returned was null, so looks like that is another dead end.

Comment: You are trying to get name of the product in client script or any other server side script

Comment: It's a scheduled script, so server side.